# Get context data from Lambda Authorizer (APi Gateway)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm using the Aws Lambda authorizer  to secure an Api gateway. The authorizer lambda function is written in python using this blueprint from aws (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints/blob/master/blueprints/python/api-gateway-authorizer-python.py)

I added this code in the "blueprint"

```
if(event['authorizationToken'] == 'allow'):
    policy.allowAllMethods()
else:
    policy.denyAllMethods()


# Finally, build the policy
authResponse = policy.build()
 
# new! -- add additional key-value pairs associated with the authenticated principal
# these are made available by APIGW like so: $context.authorizer.<key>
# additional context is cached
context = {
    'key': 'somevalue, # $context.authorizer.key -> value
    'number' : 1,
    'bool' : True
}
# context['arr'] = ['foo'] <- this is invalid, APIGW will not accept it
# context['obj'] = {'foo':'bar'} <- also invalid
 
authResponse['context'] = context

return authResponse
```

However in the lambda function attached to the route i cannot find the context value from authorizer.  How can i get the values from context[key] ?

Comment: Did you try `context.authorizer.key`?

Comment: yes - not working - "errorMessage": "'LambdaContext' object has no attribute 'authorizer'",

Comment: Let's try `event.requestContext.authorizer.key`

Comment: same thing- "errorMessage": "'dict' object has no attribute 'requestContext'" . I'm reading trogh documentation and i may need to use some mapping on integration response (api gatway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use Mapping Templates on Integration Request. If you look at the route pipeline you will see that before reaching the Lambda Function you have a "Integration Request" section (and also a Integration Response)

In Integration Request you have the option to edit the input into lambda function via Mapping Templates.

So, i created a new Mapping Template ( use "Where" there are no Templates defined)
Content -Type use application/json
and in the actual template use something like
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))

```
{
 "key":"$context.authorizer.key"
}
```

Attention : the above template will remove the original output. That data is found in $inputRoot and you can add it to response using this format

```
{
    "key":"$context.authorizer.key",
    "originalkey":$inputRoot.originalkey
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of accepted answer I had came up with this:

```html
##  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html
##  This template will pass through all parameters including path, querystring, header, stage variables, and context through to the integration endpoint via the body/payload
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
#set($authorizer = $context.authorizer)
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
    #foreach($key in $inputRoot.keySet())
    "$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($inputRoot.get($key))"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end,
    "context" : {
        "params" : {
            #foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
                #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
                "$type" : {
                    #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
                    "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
                        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
                    #end
                }
                #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
            #end
        },
        "stage-variables" : {
            #foreach($key in $stageVariables.keySet())
            "$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($stageVariables.get($key))"
                #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
            #end
        },
        #foreach($key in $context.keySet())
        "$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($context.get($key))"
            #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end,
        "authorizer": {
            #foreach($key in $authorizer.keySet())
            "$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($authorizer.get($key))"
                #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
            #end
        }
    }
}
```

edit:
after tweaking around in api gateway I'we found out about
[Use Lambda Proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html) toggle button that adds extra parameters to event object